# Unsafe javascript attempt to access frame with url Facebook with Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, unsafe, facebook-sharer

I have a problem with the Facebook plugin with Google Chrome browser. When will I recommend a post without being logged into facebook I have no problems.

But if I'm already logged into facebook and I recommend(share) a post I got the following error:

"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL"

Anybody have some idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a well-known Chrome issue.
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17325